# Unable to reach the API end point, on successive post call using Rest Assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

Find below my scenario:

1. Post to API1, Extract a value from output json

   Code:

   ```
   Response response = given().header("Accept", "application/json").spec(requestSpec)
                      .when().post(API1)
                      .then().contentType(ContentType.JSON.extract().response();
   ```
2. Post to API2 using the value extracted above.

   Code:

   ```
   Response response = given().headers("Authorization",authProp, "Content-Type","application/json").body(jsonString)
                      .when().post(API2)
                      .then().extract().response();
   ```

Issue:

When both are run in sequence (One Execution) Response of API2 is 404 not found, whereas if I run API1(1st Execution) store value to file in an execution close it. 
Then execute post to API2 (2nd execution)its successful (201 created status line is seen)

Please suggest if I missed something? i tried with Restassured.reset() in between the requests as well but same problem.

Note: Through postman, I am not seeing this issue.

Comment: i tried RestAssured.reset() before posting the second request ie:API2

Comment: Modified my post req for API1 by removing the Specbuilder, still no change. Now my post request to API1 looks as below: `Response response = given().header("Accept", "application/json","Content-Type","application/json").body(bodystring).when().post(API1).then().contentType(ContentType.JSON.extract().response();`

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved: API1 works with proxy set while API2 doesnt with proxy! But i still wonder postman was smart to handle the proxy
while rest assured wasn't. Could that be an improvement required, pick up proxy\non proxy from maven settings?

Comment: ,Please send me Proxy settings code in Rest Assured,i'm facing problem.